# Rendering 2 outputs from 1 reactive script

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378724/getting-multiple-outputs-from-reactive) regarding getting multiple outputs from a reactive script, but this still assumes that both will be used in the same object which is ultimately output. However, even if I get this working, I'm concerned that using these outputs from 2 different renderSomething({}) functions will mean my reactive script has to run twice each time.

My original code is quite lengthy, so I'll just include where I'm having an issue:

```
#main function
    server<-function(input, output){
    main<-reactive({

    #a bunch of stuff producing what it needed for output

    if(nglabels>0){
        #return number of labelings:
        outputText<-paste("Graph has",nglabels,"graceful labelings",sep=" ",collapse=NULL)
        #return FedgeLabel for graph:
        outputGraph<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(FedgeLabel,mode=c("undirected"),weighted=TRUE,add.colnames=FvertexLabel,add.rownames=FvertexLabel)
      } else {
        outputText<-"No graceful labels"
        #return imported graph as-is
        outputGraph<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat,mode=c("undirected"))
      }
      #reactive in R only allows 1 output, so we need to make a list of these:
      outputList<-list(outputText=outputText,outputGraph=outputGraph)
      return(outputList)
      })
#outputting what was calculated
    output$txt<-renderText({
        getOutput<-main()
        getOutput$outputText})
    output$Graph<-renderPlot({
        getOutput<-main()
        plot(getOutput$outputGraph)})
    } #this is the end brace from the server function
```

Of course, as of right now, neither is returning correctly, but given computation times could get large depending on input, I would much rather find an elegant way to get my outputs out of just the one reactive function.

Comment: Remove the brackets when you're assigning the reactive object to `main` on the second line.

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that when posting. Still getting a "subscript out of bounds" on my outputs though, which I'm assuming means the values didn't make it out of the reactive part correctly.

Comment: If you add `observe(print(str(main())))` outside of the `reactive()` calls and run the app, what does it say in the console?

Comment: It gives me "Warning: Error in read.table: 'file' must be a character string or connection" a bunch of times. In that same reactive() it imports a file, and the text output and graph are blank until that file is imported.

Comment: I think the error lies where you have code replaced by `#a bunch of stuff producing what it needed for output`, specifically where you are using `read.table()`.

Comment: What's strange is I never use read.table()... here's the full code: https://pastebin.com/tv9bFsjP

Comment: Reactive functions execute only when a reactive value change... Once they are executed they are like a value that you can use many times.. You can use the same reactive funciton (main) is many render functions and it will execute one time for all the outputs...

Comment: You may not be using the read.table function directly but you're using a function that uses it under the hood. The best troubleshooting route is to comment out blocks of code and see if you can pinpoint where it happens.

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Comment: Follow up- my output passing was working just fine, what was happening was read.csv was interpreting the first line of the .csv as gibberish due to some sort of UTF-8 thing above my head (I'm in Linux), and that not being a square matrix produced a ton of bugs in the rest of the code. Thanks again. Here's a link to what was going wrong all along- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568056/rs-read-csv-prepending-1st-column-name-with-junk-text